# Azure Cosmos DB for MongoDB (vCore) connection string not valid exception

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongovcore

I've set up a free cosmos DB for mongoDB vcore database without any issues, I've then been able to utilise the provided connection string to connect to the database with my credentials on both MongoDBCompass and also Azure Data Studio which confirms the string is working and allows access to the database in question.

However, when I have then used the given string in my .Net 8 C# application with MongoDb.Driver with the correct username and password inserted <username>:<password> I get the following exception every time it tries to set up the client:

MongoDB.Driver.MongoConfigurationException: The connection string 'mongodb+srv://<hidden>@mongodb-test.mongocluster.cosmos.azure.com/?tls=true&authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-256&retrywrites=false&maxIdleTimeMS=120000' is not valid.

**The code to populate the client is:**

```
public NetworkService(IOptions<MongoDBSettings> mongoDBSettings)
 {
    _client = new MongoClient(mongoDBSettings.Value.ConnectionLocal);
 }
```

I've double checked the mongoDBSettings.Value.ConnectionLocal property and this is populated with the correct string given by azure cosmos db so I'm uncertain as to why I'm getting this error saying the string is not valid.

This code also executes perfectly fine and APIs all work as expected when I point ConnectionLocal string at my local mongodb database:

"ConnectionLocal": "mongodb://localhost:27017/",

Answer (score 1):

Figured out what the issue was - my password had an @ symbol in it and it looks like the client set up was then failing as it took this symbol to signify the end of the password ahead of the expected @

Encoding the symbol as %40 fixed the issue.